# Prove that $(a+b, a-b) \ge (a, b)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

*Note: $(x,y) := \gcd(x, y)$*

**Problem:**

> Prove that $$(a+b, a-b) \ge (a,b)$$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$

**Method:**

I used this method which failed.

$$(a+b, a-b) = \min \{(a+b)x+(a - b)y | x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}  $$
$$                = \min \{a(x+y) + b(x-y)| x,y \in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
$$                = \min \{am + bn| m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\}
                = (a, b)$$

which is obviously not what I was supposed to prove :(

Please note that I was able to prove this question later using another method $\Rightarrow$
Let $(a,b) = d$ then $a = dk$ and $b = dl$ for some $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Now, $(a+b, a-b) = (d(k+l), d(k-l)) = d(k+l, k-l) \ge d = (a,b)$ Q.E.D.

**Question:**

> What was the problem with my first method?

Comment: Your minima don't exist, since you are allowing $(a+b)x+(a-b)y$ to be negative. Also you can't express every combination $am+bn$ as $a(x+y)+b(x-y)$ since in the latter case the difference of coefficients is $2y$ which is even.

Comment: @Christoph Thank you for your quick observation! :) However, I do not know why cannot I express $(a,b) = \text{least +tive value of } am+bn$ if $m-n=2k$ ($k \in N$) i.e. difference of coefficients is even?

Comment: Sure, if $m-n$ is even you can express $m$ as $x+y$ and $n$ as $x-y$. However for arbitrary $m,n\in\mathbb Z$, you don't have $m-n$ even! So allowing arbitrary $m,n$ gives you a larger set of combinations, which might yield a smaller minimum.

Comment: @Christoph I don't think I get it. Could you please explain your second point in an answer?

Comment: Sure, give me a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sets
$$
A = \mathbb N \cap \left\{\, a(x+y) + b (x-y) \,\middle|\, x,y\in\mathbb Z\,\right\}
$$
and
$$
B = \mathbb N \cap \left\{\, an + bm \,\middle|\, n,m\in\mathbb Z\,\right\}
$$
are not equal in general. Obviously $A\subseteq B$, since we can choose $n=x+y$ and $m=x-y$, which are both integers. However, in general $B$ is *not* a subset of $A$. Take $an+bm\in B$. If you try to have $n=x+y$ and $m=x-y$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$, you end up with
$$
x = \frac{n+m}{2}, \quad y = \frac{n-m}{2}.
$$
These $x$ and $y$ are not integers, if $n-m$ is not even!

From $A\subseteq B$ however, you can indeed conclude $\min A \ge \min B$, which is what you wanted to show.